# UTF-8 Unicode Error in Latex Document

Tags: unicode, utf-8, latex

I was wondering if someone can help me with that latex error.

Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:̈ not set up for use with LaTeX.

The Latex compiler can't compile and stops at a line, with an umlaut.

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969041/package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8%CE%B2-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out what the error was.

The problem was that I just copied some pdf text into the Latex document. Luckily the compiler told me, where exactly the problem was. As I mentioned above it's an umlaut. So I just retyped it and that's it.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: That was exactly my case. After two hours it finally works. Thanks!